# javascript function call automatically on page onload instead on onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I am facing a very strange problem.

I have javascript function in my aspx page that i call on the onclick event.but on one particular machine it always automatically called on body onload in infinite loop.

Though I already remove all the caching and delte the history and temp files.

This seems very strange to me .It works fine on all the machine excpt one.

The machine have windows 7 and IE verison 8.0.7600.16385

Can some one please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you possibly provide the page in question?

Comment: If you can add some sample code that would help in diagnosing the issue

Comment: How do you bind the event? How is the function defined?

Comment: If you view the source of the page of the machine it causes issues, is this differen't to that on your machine?
Otherwise try view source on your machine and save as html, then run this on the problematic machine to see if the problem still happens.

Comment: You should show the code, or atleast a minified version of it that reproduces the problem. Common mistake: Do check if you really bind the function to onclick, and not the function result (by calling the function using parentheses() after its name).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely something to do with how the JavaScript is defined, and IE8 doesn't like it.  Unfortunately, we can't really help you without seeing any code...